# Azure Service Bus :: MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync to receive multiple messages

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I need queue messages at given interval of time from queue. I tried to use

```
MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(int numberOfMessages,TimeSpan)
```

It should returns `Task<IList<Message>>` but it is returning only one message

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behaviour. The specifed number of messages will not be returned from the Queue.

Try setting prefetchcount property while receiving messages from Queue to overcome this challange.

Comment: I set prefetch count property but it is only return 15 messages.

Comment: What is the number of messages you specified within the receive method? Increasing the timeout will help.

Comment: I specified number of messages - 100 and time out of 10 secionds

Comment: It will only receive messages for 10 seconds, that's why you are getting less number of messages. Set the timeout to a higher value and trying might help.